# Mean vs. residual parameterization in JAGS/BUGS

Tags: bayesian, mcmc, jags, winbugs, parameterization

I have two different versions of a state-space model in JAGS. Both yield equivalent inferences, but are wildly different in terms of run-time and convergence. The only difference between the two is the way of expressing process error. This happens a few times in the model, but I'll just include one line for simplicity:

```
## (1) residual parameterization
rate[i] <- rate[i-1] + eps[i]
eps[i] ~ dnorm(0, tau_eps)
```

vs.

```
## (2) mean parameterization
rate[i] ~ dnorm(rate[i-1], tau_eps)
```

Version 2 of the model runs much faster (in about one tenth the amount of time!) but is much slower to converge. In fact, version 2 takes about ten times as many iterations to do so, so the two models take an equivalent amount of time. I also notice that version 1 seems much more stable with respect to latent states (`rate[i]`, etc.) at each time step , whereas version 2 seems much more stable with respect to model hyperparameters (`tau_eps`, etc.) when compared for a similar run time (20k iterations for version 1, and 200k iterations for version 2.) I should note that I'm basing my assessment of convergence/stability mostly on trace plots, but my assessments are corroborated by values of Rhat and n.eff.

**What's going on?** In my mind, the two statements above are mathematically equivalent (and indeed, both give equivalent inferences) but why should behavior in JAGS be so different? Are the two statements above less equivalent than I thought?

Comment: This is an interesting question to which I don't know the answer, but you might have more luck on the [JAGS forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/)